# ATL Dll Fails to register with XP

Tags: windows, com, dll

I created a simple COM object with ATL VS 2008. I can successfully register the dll in my machine and use it.

However, I tried to register the dll with a XP installed machine with **no** VS 2008 installed. But this does not seem to be work.

Then, I installed the VC 2008 redistributable SP1, and tried. Still the registration is failed.

Then, I did a static build of the dll and tried with the same machine and still with no success.

Can you please help me to figure out what is happening here ?

Thank you

**EDIT**

I found that ATL dll can be redistributed with following runtime libraries

\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.ATL\
 atl90.dll, 
 Microsoft.VC90.ATL.manifest

Any idea where to put these files in a client machine ?

**EDIT**

After been tried number of ways, finally I did a static build for both ATL and **MFC**.
Amazingly it worked. But I have not used any of MFC libraries inside ATL dll, Could 
someone please explain, why MFC libraries are needed ?

Answer (score 1):

In the Visual studio tools folder should be a tool called [depends.exe](http://dependencywalker.com/)

Use it to load your ATL dll on the machine where it is failing, it should tell you if you have any missing dlls.

Comment: Thank you for information, I will try it and put the result back

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make sure you have the correct vc2008 runtime installed,
I have 4 on my machine:

- 9.0.21022,
- 9.0.30729,
- 9.0.30929.17,
- 9.0.3.30729.4148.

you can check the .manifest file for which version your dll depends on. and also make sure to ship the .manifest file along with the dll unless you know how not to depend on it.

Comment: I'm having v9.0.21022.8, How can find the compatible redistributable package ?

Comment: from microsoft:http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en or from the SDK folder c:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v6.0A/Bootstrapper/Packages/vcredist_x86